# ng test --code-coverage not printing coverage details

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, karma-coverage

> When I run the tests using `ng test --code-coverage` I get the code coverage as unknown, not sure what might be going wrong. Any help here is appreciated.

```html
> ng test --code-coverage

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active26 06 2018 11:00:51.088:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
26 06 2018 11:00:51.095:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
26 06 2018 11:00:51.095:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
26 06 2018 11:00:51.100:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
26 06 2018 11:01:48.404:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/    
26 06 2018 11:01:48.665:INFO [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)]: Connected on socket UhrUQZiU8ZuG8qRwAAAA with id 31579746
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 1151 of 2149 (skipped 843) SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
26 06 2018 11:07:31.910:WARN [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 1151 of 2149 (skipped 843) DISCONNECTED (5 mins 31.686 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 1151 of 2149 (skipped 843) DISCONNECTED (5 mins 31.686 secs / 0 secs)

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 1295 of 2149 (skipped 854) DISCONNECTED (6 mins 49.413 secs / 0 secs)
```

Comment: Go to ./coverage folder at your project root. You can then open ./coverage/index.html to see the coverage report.

Comment: coverage/index.html also shows coverage as unknown..

Comment: I am facing the same have you found any solution

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it by making sure the `"sourceRoot"` property in the `angular.json` is set to the root folder for the project's source files.

The `ng` cli [uses the files in `"sourceRoot"` to compute coverage](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/317121a32520eafc0c9303b562d0b81b0d2b725f/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/karma/code-coverage_spec.ts#L65).

It doesn't seem to do anything else with `sourceRoot` for tests, so the tests run and pass, but coverage doesn't work.