# Karma , Istanbul - code coverage report Unknown% ( 0/0 )

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test, karma-coverage

I'm getting this Coverage Summary

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
```

I applied the changes instructed in the Angular Documentation for code 
coverage:
https://angular.io/guide/testing#enable-code-coverage-report

but I keep getting the same empty summery.

my karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/singleWindow'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      thresholds: {
        statements: 80,
        lines: 80,
        branches: 80,
        functions: 80
      }
       },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
});
}
```

Comment: did you figured it out?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51049229/573685).

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue with Angular 7 when running tests using `ng test`.

As it turns out, Angular CLI disable code coverage by default. You have to start your tests using `ng test --code-coverage` for it to work.

You can make it always on by adding `"codeCoverage": true` to the `test` task of your `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "name-of-your-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          /* ... */
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "codeCoverage": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more informations: https://angular.io/guide/testing#enable-code-coverage-reports

Comment: 4 years later, this fixed my problem. Also, it's better to use the variable at the angular.json

Answer (score 7):

When the coverage is `Unknown%` that means you've probably *enabled* it correctly.

Make sure the `"sourceRoot"` property in the `angular.json` is set to the root folder for the project's source files.

The `ng` cli [uses the files in `"sourceRoot"` to compute coverage](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/317121a32520eafc0c9303b562d0b81b0d2b725f/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/karma/code-coverage_spec.ts#L65).

It doesn't seem to do anything else with `sourceRoot` for tests, so the tests run and pass, but coverage doesn't work.

Comment: `sourceRoot` was the issue in my case, thank @sorohan

Comment: Hi @sorohan, this is what I have for sourceRoot, "sourceRoot": "src",. is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue for the code coverage both ways: command line or configuration.

Solution:
We need to check the other component and spec files for errors because when we run `ng test --code-coverage` it's compiling the all files. So please ensure all spec and component files are without error.

Files with errors can be the reason you're not able get code coverage. If so, it shows the code coverage as below:

```
==================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )               
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )          
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )      
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
```

After fixing all component and spec file errors, I get code coverage successfully:

```
================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 85% ( 17/20 )    
Branches     : 0% ( 0/2 )   
Functions    : 83.33% ( 5/6 )    
Lines        : 84.21% ( 16/19)
```